# How to align website header using CSS or jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am using code:

```
<script>

jQuery('div.io-title-description').attr('align', 'center');

</script>

<style>

div.io-title-description { text-align: center; }

div.io-title-description a:first-child { font-size: 36; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase; color: #1E73BE; text-shadow: 0px 0px; text-decoration: none; }

</style>
```

to align header of my website: https://news.softsolutionslimited.com

The CSS code is setting all other CSS properties except `align` in both `jQuery` and `CSS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your website. And I have made few changes to classes:

```
.io-title-description {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 17px 0;
    padding: 14px 0;
    float: none;
    width: 75%;             /* After width is given inline-block will align center */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* padding included inside width */
}
.socialmedia {
    float: right;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 25%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;  /* Padding included */
}
```

Changes I made, added width to `.io-title-description` and `border-box` to both of them. Because, I added width, the `inline-block` element will know the width of line and if there is no other element, then it will align items to center. `border-box` give padding to the element but padding is included inside the width, i.e `width` will always be same(75%, in this case).

*Note:- I think now you don't have to add jquery to align center, as you have already use somewhere in parent.